# react redux work unexpected when store state change

Tags: reactjs, redux, containers, state, connect

I am in confusion.

I'm using react-redux for my container

My code is as follows

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    post : state.post
})

const PostContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this.state = {
           post : props.post
       }
    }

    render(){
          <div>
               {post.title}
          </div>
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PostContainer)
```

The odd part of this code is as follows.

Now here in my code I only get the state in the first construction and then I do not get the new data in the state.

but !!

When postState in store changes, PostContainer State also changes

why ???

Even though I did not handle new data in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

thank you ...

Comment: You are trying to get an initian post state from a parent component which I think is not the desired behave, if PostContainer is a container in fact you should give to post some initial value, let's say empty string "", which eventually will receive some value from store after you change the store state. Anyway could you explain better where are you getting props from? A parent component or store?

Answer (score 1):

with little changes, your code will work as expected

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class PostContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <div>{this.props.post.title}</div>;
    ) 
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  post: state.post
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PostContainer);
```